# Simulation of binomial random variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, simulation

I am getting started in R. I need help with a command to:

"Simulate 10000 binom(20,0.3)-RV's". I would do it like:

```
binsim <- rbinom(10000, 20, 0.3)
```

Question cont.: "Let X be a binomial(20,0.3)-RV. Use simulated numbers to estimate:
P(X<=5) and P(X=5)"

Okay for the first I would use: `pbinom(???)` and for the second `dbinom(?????)`

How do I connect the simulation results from `binsim and the X-RV's to get the required probabilities?

Could I do it with `length(binsim(binsim<=5)/length(binsim)`?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: not really, it is an exercise from the book by Brown and Murdoch, First Course in stat. progr. with R, Doing it also as a possible prep. for an actuarial course. Regards

Comment: gung, Thanks, just did it. Q: how could I store ocram's answer, will it stay in my account as long as I wish? Sorry, Q is serious. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. CV is [intended](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about) as both a simple Q&A site and also a dynamic, permanent repository of knowledge. This question will remain listed on your user page under the questions you've asked. You & any future visitor will be able to access & learn from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions like `pbinom()`, `ppois()`,... are used to compute the *true* values of $\Pr(X \leq x)$. Similarly, `dbinom()`, `dpois()`,... are used to compute *true* values of $\Pr(X = x)$. Here you are asked to perform simulations. Simulations are relevant when you do not have closed-form expressions for $\Pr(X \leq x)$ or $\Pr(X = x)$. The basic idea is to draw a sample and to evaluate the empirical version of the quantity of interest. For example, if you have drawn $\{0, 2, 7, 3, 10\}$, the empirical version of $\Pr(X \leq 2)$ is $$\frac{\#\{0, 2\}}{\#\{0, 2, 7, 3, 10\}}= \frac{2}{5}=0.4.$$

We do have closed-form expressions for the binomial random variable but, as pointed out by @gung, this looks like an exercice. So, here is an example to help.

---

Let $X \sim N(\mu=3, \sigma^2 = 1.3)$. We know that $\textrm{E}(X) = \mu = 3$ and that $\textrm{Var}(X) = \sigma^2 = 1.3$, but let us check that by simulations:

```
> x <- rnorm(1000, mean=3, sd=sqrt(1.3))
> mean(x)
[1] 3.078271
> var(x)
[1] 1.315806
```

---

You might find useful to type `help(dbinom)` first...

Comment: ocram, thanks, your answer helped me. Unfortunately, in my stat.-courses I never came across simulations, (as far as I remember). Sorry if you receive three times the same answer. This exercise is from book by J. Brown and D. Murdoch.